# Use of \pause in \note{} environment

Tags: beamer, notes, pause, pgfpages

Is it somehow possible to use `\pause` in the `\note{}` environment?

In the example, so that "item 2" on slide and in notes pop up at the same time?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item item 1 \pause
    \item item 2
\end{itemize}
\note{\begin{itemize}
    \item item 1 \pause
    \item item 2
\end{itemize}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The \pause command in the notes section doesn't do anything here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass overlay instructions to the `\note` command which specify on which overlays the note should be displayed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item item 1 \pause
    \item item 2
\end{itemize}
\note<1->[item]{item 1}
\note<2>[item]{item 2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Dirk You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

For completeness: instead of `show notes on second screen` you can also use `second mode text on second screen` which allows you to create a parallel presentation on the second screen. This does not provide the visual features of the `note` environment (like the small version of the presentation slide) but it does give some flexibility in using overlay specifications.

An example that comes close to your question uses `\alt<second>`, another example uses `\only`, as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{second mode text on second screen}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[typeset second]
\frametitle{\texttt{alt<second>}}
\begin{itemize}
    \alt<second>{
    \item note item 1\pause
    \item note item 2
   }{
        \item item 1\pause
        \item item 2
    }
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[typeset second]
\frametitle{\texttt{only}}
\begin{itemize}
    \only<second:0>{\item item 1}
    \only<second>{\item note item 1}\pause
    \only<second:0>{\item item 2}
    \only<second>{\item note item 2}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]